# Convert Rational Function to Finite Continuted Functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, continued-fractions

If we have a finite continued rational functions, it is easy to clear the demoninator and write as a rational function (quotient of polynomials). For example,$$ \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+1}}}=\frac{x^{2}+x+1}{x^{3}+x^{2}+2x+1}$$
My question is how to go from the right to the left? I know that division algorithm is one way, but somehow it does not give me the finite continued function that I want. Therefore, I am really appreciate it if someone can let me know whether there are other ways.

To be more specific, the rational function that I really care about is the following:
$$
\frac{-x^{2}-x+1}{x^{3}-2x^{2}-x+1}.
$$
Somehow I need to convert it as a two-layer finite continued function. Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Comment: What goes wrong when you try to solve the problem using polynomial division?

Comment: In this case, the continued rational function generated from the division algorithm is quite ugly and the pattern is not clear. I am hoping to get a continued rational function whose pattern is clear so that I can add more and more layers, leading to a sequence of finite continued rational functions.

Comment: I think you should do the work with your second rational function and then tell us what you don't like about the result. If you want a simple continued fraction representation (denominators all $1$), then I don't think you have any choice: the representation is determined by the polynomial division process.

Answer (score 3):

Diving a polynomial by other you get $$a(x) = b(x) q(x)+r(x)$$ so $$\frac{a(x)}{b(x)} = q(x)+\frac{r(x)}{b(x)}= q(x)+\frac{1}{b(x)/r(x)}$$

Now repeat the process with $b(x)$ and $r(x)$.

Comment: Thanks very much! However, the division algorithm somehow does not give me the "correct" finite continued fractions in this case (they are not beautiful enough). Is there any other method?

Comment: @Apple What do you mean? What did you get and what did you expect?